# How to set gRPC Client Timeout for all requests in Java / Kotlin / Android

Tags: android, grpc, grpc-java

I am trying to start using grpc for Android.

I found how to set timeout (deadline) for single request.

Is there any way to set timeout for all requests? I really do not want to set deadline before every request

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use service config to provide defaults on a per-method basis, or you can use an interceptor to set deadlines at a channel-level.

[Service config](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/service_config.md) can be specified via `managedChannelBuilder.defaultServiceConfig(Map)`. You can choose to set different timeouts based on different methods. Ideally this configuration would be managed by the service owner.

```java
Map<String, Object> wildcardConfig = new HashMap<>();
wildcardConfig.put("name", Collections.singletonList(
    // This would specify a service+method if you wanted
    // different methods to have different settings
    Collections.emptyMap()));
wildcardConfig.put("timeout", "10s");
channelBuilder.defaultServiceConfig(
    Collections.singletonMap("methodConfig", Collections.singletonList(
        wildcardConfig)));
```

Interceptors can be added to a stub via `stub.withInterceptors()`. Creating an interceptor that would add default timeouts would look like:

```java
class TimeoutInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor {
  @Override public <ReqT,RespT> ClientCall<ReqT,RespT>  interceptCall(
      MethodDescriptor<ReqT,RespT> method, CallOptions callOptions, Channel next) {
    callOptions = callOptions.withDeadlineAfter(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return next.newCall(method, callOptions);
  }
}

stub = stub.withInterceptors(new TimeoutInterceptor());
```

Comment: I set TimeoutInterceptor for ManagedChanel, not for all stubs. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know any realisations of request LoggingInterceptor?

Comment: If you're using springboot autoconfiguration just annotate with @GrpcGlobalServerInterceptor to make it global.